# NodeJS Q Promise erroring "has no method 'then'"

Tags: node.js, q

I'm working on implementing a promise (first time using them with node) but I keep getting the error:

```
TypeError: Object function (){
    Users.findById(req.body.receiver).exec(function (err, user){
    if(err) return handleError(err);
    if(user.local.email ){
      return email = user.local.email
    }
    if(user.facebook.email){
      return email = user.facebook.email
    }
  })
  } has no method 'then'
```

Judging by the error I'm going to have to guess there is something wrong with `return function()`?

Here is my function:

```
exports.sendEmail = function(req,res){
  function findEmail(){
    return function(){
      Users.findById(req.body.receiver).exec(function (err, user){
        if(err) return handleError(err);
          if(user.local.email ){
          return email = user.local.email
        }
        if(user.facebook.email){
          return email = user.facebook.email
        }
      })
    }
  }

  findEmail().then(function(email){
    // do stuff
  })
}
```

Comment: `findEmail()().then(`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function findEmail(){
  return function(){
    return Q();
  };
}
findEmail(); // returns a function
```

In your example the `findEmail` returns a function that if called returns a promise. However your attempting to use the returned function as if it was a promise which it isn't it's a function.

Two ways to fix:

```
findEmail()(); // returns the promise
```

Or refactor the function:

```
function findEmail() {
  return Q();
}
findEmail(); // returns the promise
```

Notice the missing `return function()`?

Comment: when I write the code like this http://pastie.org/9721679 it returns the whole JSON object, not just the email object like I am trying to get.  Do you have any suggestions on how to get just the email?  Thank you for your help thus far.

I do see now how having my main function return another function was causing a problem though.

Comment: Does exec execute synchronously? If not then the Q promise isn't resolving like you think it should. You probably want something like Q.defer() or simular. Try asking about that pastie in another question.

Answer (score 0):

Too much nesting? Do you really need that extra function wrapper?

```
exports.sendEmail = function(req,res){
  function findEmail(){
    Users.findById(req.body.receiver).exec(function (err, user){
      if(err) return handleError(err);
        if(user.local.email ){
        return email = user.local.email
      }
      if(user.facebook.email){
        return email = user.facebook.email
      }
    })
  }

  findEmail().then(function(email){
    // do stuff
  })
}
```

EDIT: I would also do some serious refactoring here, promisify stuff (mixing callbacks and promises is just not great visually, promisified code looks a lot better), avoid a named function if it's only used internally and once, etc...